# Find replace across multiple lines in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to replace instances of a string beginning with START and ending with END in a file, across multiple lines, in perl?

i.e. input:

```
good
START
bad
bad
END
good
```

Then find the range from START to END, and replace with 'replaced':

```
good
replaced
good
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes. You need a multi-line regular expression. The `m` modifier to your pattern will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag. Something like the following:

```
perl -ne '$inside = print "replaced\n" if /START/;
          print unless $inside;
          undef $inside if /END/' file
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to combine this with find to change the files?

Comment: @James: `find . -type f ... -exec perl -i~ -ne ... {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flip-flop `..` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
perl -pe '$_ = $i == 1 ? "replaced$/" : "" if $i = /START/ .. /END/' file
```

`$i` count lines from `START` to `END`, or it holds false value when outside start-end block.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Perl program which replaces the strings between START and END (Case insensitive) as shown in the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $InFile = $ARGV[0];
    my $document = do {
        local $/ = undef;
        open my $fh, "<", $InFile or die "Error: Could Not Open File $InFile: $!";
      <$fh>;
    };
    $document =~ s/\bSTART\b.*?\bEND\b/replaced/isg;
    print $document;
```